# How to have the screen divided into two halves and have all Composable children respect this contraint?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have this code in Kotlin:

```kotlin
Column {
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceAround
        ) {
            Text("String1")
            Text("String2")
        }

        Row(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceAround
        ) {
            Text("String3")
            Column {
                OutlinedTextField(modifier = Modifier.height(30.dp), value = "", onValueChange = {})
                OutlinedTextField(modifier = Modifier.height(30.dp), value = "", onValueChange = {})
            }
        }
    }
```

which produces this layout:

[image]

I would like "String3" to be aligned with "String1", while having the two `OutlinedTextField`s to be half the size of the screen. Basically, I need the screen to be exactly divided into two halves and have every child respect this requirement. Is there a way to do so without explicitly specify the width of the children?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to apply `weight` on `Modifier` on both children inside the `Row`

```
 Row(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceAround,
        ) {
            Text("String3", modifier = Modifier.weight(1F))
            Column(modifier = Modifier.weight(1F)) {
                OutlinedTextField(modifier = Modifier.height(30.dp), value = "", onValueChange = {})
                OutlinedTextField(modifier = Modifier.height(30.dp), value = "", onValueChange = {})
            }
        }
```

You will see like this

[image]

then the `Alignment` part you have to apply `textAlign = TextAlign.Center` on the String3 Text.

```
 Text("String3", modifier = Modifier.weight(1F), textAlign = TextAlign.Center)
```

So finally you will get.

[image]